# Favicon shows incorrect image

Tags: favicon

I have a page which was copied from another site and modified. I am referring to a favicon in my new site. When I view the page it's showing the correct favicon, but when view the source it's showing the favicon for the older site.

What could be the problem?

Comment: your new site refers to the new favicon using the new URL?  so how come when you view source, it shows the URL of the older site?

Answer (score 1):

Favicon caching in browsers is virtually impossible to control. Even if you clear your cache, the browser probably won't clear favicons until a random time in the future it feels like doing so.

New users of your site will see the new favicon. Old users will eventually see the new icon.

Comment: But I have a newly installed Chrome in my system. So I think this is not a caching issue.